# Inserting different values from a row from 'Patients' table to 'visits' table as different entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am in a predicament where I have to take some values from one row from Patient's table and insert them into a different table (Visits) but each as a different row. Is there any way to do this in using SQL?

Patients Table:

```
| Jan       | Feb        |   March    | Apr  |  May      | June     |UniqueID|
| NULL      | 2018-02-01 | 2019-03-01 | NULL |2018-05-01 |  NULL    | 1      |
| 2019-01-01| 2019-02-01 | NULL       | NULL | NULL      |2018-06-01| 2      |
```

Expected Visits Table:

```
|   UniqueID        |   DateOfVist   |
|   1               |   2018-02-01   |
|   1               |   2019-03-01   | 
|   1               |   2018-05-01   |
|   2               |   2018-06-01   |  
|   2               |   2019-01-01   |
|   2               |   2019-02-01   |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `cross apply` pretty much does what you want:

```
select t.uniqueid, v.dateofvisit
from t cross apply
     (values (jan), (feb), (mar), (apr), (may), (jun)
     ) v(dateofvisit)
where v.dateofvisit is not null;
```

You can add `insert into visits (uniqueid, dateofvisit)` or `into visits` to (respectively) load or create a `visits` table.

Comment: Thank you Gordon!
This is a precise solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
insert into visits (UniqueID, DateOfVist   )
    select UniqueID, dateofvisist
    from patients t cross apply
         ( values (Jan), (Feb), . .  ) t(dateofvisist)
    where dateofvisist is not null;
```